# How to eliminate carriage return from google sheet email send app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a sample app script from Google that sends emails from a spreadsheet using data in the columns. It works ok except the message seems to put a carriage return after a random number of spaces, in other words, the message doesn't fill up the whole line, it breaks after about 76 characters. I included the email result from gmail and another mail program so you can see the results are the same. I put the message in a column and hard coded here as a variable and the results are the same. Appreciate any help or ideas, thank you.

```
/**
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    //var message = row[3]; // Second column
     var message = 'Unfortunately the XXXXX you inquired about was sold recently. However, we have an excellent selection of other similar vehicles at that price range and have new inventory coming in daily. Please try these tools to help you with your South Easton Motor Sales vehicle selection.';
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try using [htmlBody](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using htmlBody works, but not if you're sending to a client that doesn't support HTML (like sending texts to phones!)